# Combining two queries in mySQL

Tags: mysql, join, union

I'm trying to combine the results of two queries. I'm not very proficient in mysql so I'm here for some help.

The first query is as follows:

```
select count(roomtypeid) as bookedrooms, day 
from event_guest_hotel 
where hotelid = 1 and roomtypeid = 1 
 group by day;
```

This returns:

[image: firstquery]

The second query:

```
SELECT ehr.reservationid, ehr.day, h.name AS hotelname, 
ehr.totalrooms as requested_rooms, r.name AS roomname
            FROM event_hotel_reservation ehr 
            INNER JOIN hotel_room_type r 
            ON ehr.roomtypeid = r.roomtypeid 
            INNER JOIN hotel h
            ON ehr.hotelid = h.hotelid  
            WHERE totalRooms != 0 
            AND reservationID = '1'
```

This returns:

[image: seconquery]

Can I combine the first query with the second one, so I get the results of the first one in another resultcolumn next to 'roomname'? That way I know how many rooms are already booked and how many were originally requested from one single query.

Comment: Do you mean another column or another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT ehr.reservationid, ehr.day, h.name AS hotelname, 
    ehr.totalrooms as requested_rooms, r.name AS roomname, 
    egh.bookedrooms
FROM event_hotel_reservation ehr 
INNER JOIN hotel_room_type r ON ehr.roomtypeid = r.roomtypeid 
INNER JOIN hotel h ON ehr.hotelid = h.hotelid    
left outer join (
    select hotelid, count(roomtypeid) as bookedrooms, day 
    from event_guest_hotel 
    where roomtypeid = 1 
    group by hotelid, day
) egh on h.hotelid = egh.hotelid and ehr.day = egh.day
WHERE totalRooms != 0 
    AND reservationID = '1'
```

Comment: Thanks. At first look this is indeed what I'm looking for. I'll try it out with this query for now, as what I'm doing exactly is a bit vague to me ;D complex applications :(

Comment: Hmm. Is there a way I can display bookedrooms as 0 for the other days? It only shows the 25th atm. Thanks

Comment: You'll want to do left outer join on the (select ...) instead of inner join. See the wikipedia article on outer joins to understand how they work:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_joins